# c++ copy array with copy constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Array{
    int size;
    int *array;
    public:
        Array(const int *);
        Array(const Array &);
        void Print();
        ~Array();   

};
```

Here my class

```
cout<<"I am constructor"<<endl;
        size=sizeof(data_in);

        array=new int[size+1];

        for(int i=0;i<size+1;i++){
            array[i]=data_in[i];
        }
```

here my constructor

```
cout<<"I am copy constructor"<<endl;
        size=sizeof(object_in);
        array=new int[size+1];

        for(int i=0;i<size+1;i++){
            array[i]=object_in.array[i];
        }
```

here my copy constructor

```
int main()
    int *a;
    a=new int[4];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        a[i]=i;
        cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        }

    Array array1(a);//Constructor invoked
    array1.Print();

    Array another=array1;//copy constructor invoked
    another.Print();
```

here is my main function.
     I want to my array copy to another array with the copy constructor.But this code isn't working properly.What can ı do simply?

Comment: _"...But this code isn't working properly..."_ is not a question.   Please reword your post.

Comment: Simply use std::vector.

Comment: Post compilable code, not snippets.

Comment: Your *"main fun"* has plain *undefined behavior* - you are iterating past the size of the allocated array. Also `sizeof` doesn't return the size of an array when used on a pointer - it returns the size of the pointer (meaning that your loops in the "constructors" also invoke *undefined behvaior*)

Comment: And even if `size` was correct in your "constructors" you are iterating until `size+1` so you would be accessing the array out of bounds

Answer (score 3):

That's what probably you want:

Array.h

```
class Array {
public:
    Array(const int *array, int size);
    Array(const Array &other);
    ~Array();
    void Print();

private:
    int m_size;
    int *m_array;
};
```

Array.cpp

```
#include "array.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

Array::Array(const int *array, int size)
    : m_size(size)
{
    std::cout << "I am constructor" << std::endl;

    m_array = new int[m_size];
    std::copy(array, array+size, m_array);
}

Array::Array(const Array &other)
    : m_size(other.m_size)
{
    std::cout << "I am copy constructor" << std::endl;

    m_array = new int[m_size];
    std::copy(other.m_array, other.m_array + m_size, m_array);
}

Array::~Array()
{
    delete [] m_array;
}

void Array::Print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<m_size; ++i) {
        std::cout << m_array[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int SIZE = 4;

    int *a;
    a = new int[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i) {
        a[i] = i;
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    Array array1(a, SIZE); // constructor invoked
    array1.Print();

    Array another(array1); // copy constructor invoked
    another.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- You should forward array size to `Array`'s constructor. `sizeof` won't work as you expect because it will return a size of pointer `int*` which is probably always 4 bytes (however it depends on a compiler);
- If you want to create an array of size of 4, then iteration over this array should be done like this: `for(int i=0; i<4; i++)`. This cycle iterates over [0; 3];
- It's not clear why do you use something like `size+1`. If you decided to have an array of size of 4, then always use 4. Going beyond space that was allocated by `new int[4]` will bring you a pain and only pain.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the array size with sizeof inside the constructor. You have to pass the length with a second parameter.

Comment: You can by doing `size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Gambit except that in the "constructor" OP has a `const int*`, not an array

Comment: @Gambit NO. Arrays (can) decay into pointers, but **not the other way round** - also you could just test it out: http://ideone.com/s8QIKQ